# Jquery - Microprocessor seamless command sending fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

In Google Chrome while using ajax method with Username, Password in URL it again asks the Username/password popup.

```
  var lummens_url = 'https://admin:9999@ip/command.htm?language=ie&';

  $.ajax({
    url: lummens_url + 'pen-tilt-zoom=' + embedded_processor_commands,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
  });
```

But same URL when i apply in --incognito address bar it works on every attempt without username/password popup to fill in again.

How can you completely avoid the $.ajax method but use something like $.iframe(submit, onsubmitfinish(){ close iframe }) ;? so that this does not annoy the end-user?

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with microprocessors? It looks like you're running into problems with credentials/cookies and requests. The title is kinda confusing.

Comment: I am using Crestron/Extron, Arduino, PCL, Embedded linux based microprocessors. Where sending commands via GET method is granted but you have to submit username/password. While using $.ajax username/password by pass does not work. But same thing when you use with Browser address bar it works. So how to make it in JQuery/Javascript please?

Comment: If they word in the address bar (horrible security), then just send them along as request params?

Comment: you have to send it as `https://username:password@ip:port/commandmodule.htm?argument1=command_details`